# Absolute position for an IMG in a LI

Tags: jquery, css, browser

I'm using jQuery to add an image in the active list element of my navigation (ul li.active). Works fine.

For a design purpose, I'd like to absolute position this img and add a `left: 50%;` to make it centered. Works fine in every browsers except Firefox(latest) on OS X and Safari on Windows XP. 
These apply the `left: 50%;` relative to the UL and not the LI with a `position: relative;`

Where it works, the image appears centered, below the content on my LI.

URL : http://aerokure.steveforest.com/produits/insecticides-pour-le-jardin.html
It's the black menu below the logo.

Tried to put a `display: block;` on the img as some suggest : nothing.

Anything?

Thanks

Comment: Always remember the web developer's mantra: If it works in IE, but not a modern browser, then my code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

i found the issue

remove height     =   ul element

Add float:left    =   li element

margin:0;         =   li element

It will work fine

Comment: If I change the display:table; to display: table-row;, on the ul, it solves the problem but I lose the border-radius...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the display of the list item from 'table-cell' to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

And then remove the:

```
margin-bottom: 8px;
```

styling. This seems to do the trick for me (Firefox on OSX).

If you put a negative margin, of half the width of the image, you can actually get it centered:

```
margin-left: -10px;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this won't help because table-cell is the only way I found to get equals LI without a width value. Very useful when the site is in a CMS, edited by a client.